# Cannot pass correctly Components to NavigatorIOS when using with TabBarIOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigator-ios

I'm new to `ReactNative` and started to using `TabBarIOS` component for a project. I have `TabBarIOS` component which has 5 different `TabBarIOS.Item` `Component`. These each all point another component to present. These different components are all have different `backgroundColor's` and styles and `titles` but when I change the `selectedTab` the change has happened but the properties of components such as `backgroundColor` not affect the presented component. For testing, I've log a text in `componentWillMount` method of the `Component` class for each one. And they logged successfully. Here is the partial components. For the first `Component` which is named as `Restaurants` the title is correctly showing in `navigationItem` but in others `navigationItem's` title is empty.

I've called my components as ViewControllers.

```
class RestaurantsComponent extends Component{

    componentWillMount(){
        console.log('restauranscomponent will mounted');
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
                <Text>ASDFSADF</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}


class SearchViewController extends Component{

    componentWillMount(){
        console.log('search view controller will mounted');
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'green'}}>
                <Text>askfkjasljkdfjkla</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

etc..

Here is main tabbar `Component` class:

```
export default class SimpleClass extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedTab: 'news'
        }
    }

    changeTab(selectedTab){
        this.setState({selectedTab})
    }

    render(){
        const { selectedTab } = this.state

        const styles = {
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        };

        return(
                    <TabBarIOS barTintColor="white"
                            unselectedItemTintColor="gray"
                            tintColor="red" 
                            style={{flex:1}}
                    >
                        <TabBarIOS.Item
                            selected={selectedTab === 'news'}
                            title="Restaurants"
                            icon={require('./assets/restaurants.png')}
                            onPress={() => this.changeTab('news')}
                        >

                        <NavigatorIOS
                                style={styles.nav}
                                initialRoute={{
                                    component: RestaurantsComponent,
                                    title : 'Restaurants'
                                   }}
                            />
                        </TabBarIOS.Item>

                        <TabBarIOS.Item
                            title="Search"
                            selected={selectedTab === 'news2'}
                            onPress={() => this.changeTab('news2')}
                            icon={require('./assets/searchIco.png')}
                        >
                            <NavigatorIOS
                                style={styles.nav}
                                initialRoute={{
                                    component: AnotherComponent,
                                    title : 'Search'
                                   }}
                            />
                        </TabBarIOS.Item>
                        ...
                          .../>
```

Here is the Component in `navigationItem` for `Restaurants`

[image]

And for other else:

[image]

I'vent cut the tabBar item for the screenshot but the `TabBarIOS` is successfully works if you mind it.

Is there any bug which is currently which cause from me or what happens to `navigationItem's` title attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer by the way I've not figured out what was happening in here but when looking into documentation and some articles, the use of `NavigatorIOS` is currently making mess.And there is a cool question & answer that I think its important to get idea of `createNavigator...` .

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631561/is-tabnavigator-deprecated).

There is a close approach for using `TabBar`, `Navigation` etc which are named `createStackNavigator` and createBottomTabNavigator. As the names tell us, `createStackNavigator` is currently work like `UINavigationController` and also `createBottomTabNavigator` is working like `UITabBarController`. So this is the basic implementation of these approach.

```
const firstTabStack = createStackNavigator({
  HomeAlways: {
    navigationOptions:{
      title:'WASSUP1'
    },
    screen:BooksNav
  }
})

const secondTabStack = createStackNavigator({
  HelpAlways: {
    navigationOptions:{
      title:'WASSUP2'
    },
    screen:AddBook
  }
})
```

And finally here we come with `Tab` implementation.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
    screen: firstTabStack,
    navigationOptions:{
      title:'title1'
    }
  },
  Another: {
    screen: secondTabStack,
    navigationOptions:{
      title:'title2'
    }
  }
});
```

What did I do with these code?

For `iOS` Developers to get understand what is going on in there, there is a 2 Controller (`UIViewController` or `Component` in RN), and these have different `UINavigationController's` and also different titles. And all of these controllers will going to stack of the `UITabBarController`' `viewControllers`.

The images in below are proof of the successfully running.
[image],
[image]